# Python GAE multiple handlers on same page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am creating a blog using Google App Engine, Python and Jinja2. I have a handler called PostPage that  displays all information about the post. I have edit, delete, like, add comments functions inside this handler. I am using Modal Boxes from Bootstrap to edit the post and comments instead of creating editPost, editComment, and like html files. I want to separate all this functions into different handlers, but I don't know if that can be done without having to create different html files and redirect to those pages. I would prefer to use the Modal Boxes instead of going to a different page to edit a post or comment.

Comment: Yes, you can create as many handlers as you need, you don't have to create separate html files per each handler, just point each modal's form's `action` parameter (if that's what you're using) to the new handler route.

In the long run your single html file will get too big though, so you may wanna think about moving the modals into separate templates and `include`ing them into to main html file but sounds like you don't need this right now...

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create several handlers and execute them when including different parameters in the form's action.